# SwiftUI Navigation. View pops immediately after being pushed. How to fix?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I found a strange bug. In one moment view started popping immediately after being pushed. I had been commenting the code piece by piece until reduced it to a minimal reproducible example.

Here is the code:

```
struct Destination : View {
    private let some: NSArray

    init(some: NSArray) {
        self.some = some
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("e")
    }
}

struct RecordingsView : View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geom in
            // Fill safe area with colors
            VStack {
                Spacer().frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: geom.safeAreaInsets.top).background(Color.red)
                Spacer().frame(maxWidth: .infinity).background(Color.white)
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

            // Main content
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                NavigationLink(
                        destination: Destination(some: NSArray(array: [34, 53, 45, 34566])).navigationBarHidden(true)
                ) {
                    Text("WhitePlusButton")
                }.padding(.trailing, 18)

                LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<1) { index in
                        NavigationLink(
                                destination: Destination(some: NSArray(array: [34, 53, 45])).navigationBarHidden(true)
                        ) {
                            Text("aaaaa")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@main
struct VocalTrainerApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                RecordingsView().navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However if I replace NSArray with Int or comment `Spacer().frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: geom.safeAreaInsets.top).background(Colors.tone2)` line, the bug is not reproduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be running into the bug where views pop immediately if there's exactly two navigation links. Try inserting a NavigationLink with EmptyViews as shown as a temporary bandaid.

```
        NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
            EmptyView()
        }
```

You can find more info here:
https://forums.swift.org/t/14-5-beta3-navigationlink-unexpected-pop/45279